# Memory leak when removeAllViewsInLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks

I am developing an application which uses FragmentPagerAdapter to manage Fragments.
Inside one of the fragments I can do the following :

- populate the fragment's view with dynamically created components (LinearLayout,ImageView, Button)
- remove the views created

However, when I try to remove the views some serious memory leaks can be noticed.
Android Profiler in Android Studio shows that most of the memory is not recuperated from the Graphics section, when I heavily(testing the product) call *populateItems()* and *clearFragment()*

Here is how I create dynamically the view components inside the Fragment:

```
@Override 
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    // populate the layouts
    populateItems(view);
    ...
}

// THIS IS THE FUNCTION USED TO POPULATE THE FRAGMENT
public void populateItems(View vw)
{
    LinearLayout horizontalView;
    ImageView faceImg;
    Button renameBtn;

    fragment_id = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_cunoscuti);

    if(fragment_id != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            String imagePath = Constants.getKnownPath() + File.separator + files[i].getName();

            // set the image view
            faceImg = new ImageView(getActivity());
            faceImg.setImageBitmap(FileUtils.getBitmapFromFile(imagePath));
            ....

            // create the button ...
            renameBtn = new Button(getActivity());

            ....
            // create this for some irrelevant reason :)
            horizontalView = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            ....
            horizontalView.addView(faceImg);
            horizontalView.addView(renameBtn);

            ....
            fragment_id.addView(horizontalView,params);
        }
}

// THIS IS THE FUNCTION USED AT SOME POINT TO CLEAR THE FRAGMENT
public void clearFragment()
{
    if(fragment_id != null)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<fragment_id.getChildCount();x++)
        {
            if(fragment_id.getChildAt(x) instanceof LinearLayout)
            {
                LinearLayout FL = (LinearLayout) fragment_id.getChildAt(x);
                FL.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            }
        }
        fragment_id.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    }

    // added just for tests
    System.gc();
}
```

Q: I queried stackoverflow for similar problems but I couldn't solve it.
How can I avoid memory leaks in my attempt to keep the functionality of cleaning the fragment view?

Thank you.

Comment: Please add more info, like the view pager code and full fragment code. Memory leaks are usually hard to find, first, use leakcanery library that may help. Then you should use android studio tools to find exactly what objects are getting leaked (run the code multiple time and observe reference count for different objects). If you post the code on github or email it me `a.ahmadi.dev@gmail.com` I can take a look myself.